# Meaning of @0 in a shell script

Tags: find

I was looking at the script `/etc/init.d/sudo` in my Ubuntu 14.04 Linux system. While reading the script, I found this statement :

```
find /var/lib/sudo -exec touch -d @0 '{}' \;
```

What is the meaning of `@0` here? What does the above statement do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That has nothing to do with `bash` or `sudo`. The `find` command is using the `-exec` action to run the given command on each file found. In this case, the command being run is

```
touch -d @0
```

If you check `man touch` on a GNU system, you will find that

```
   -d, --date=STRING
          parse STRING and use it instead of current time
```

So, the `-d` is a way of choosing the date you want `touch` to set for the target file. The `@` tells the GNU implementation of `touch` that this is a date defined as [seconds since the epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Since it is actually 0 seconds, this means the very beginning of UNIX time. An easy way to check this is to give the same date to the GNU `date` command:

```
$ TZ=UTC date -d @0
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970
```

So, the command you showed will find all files and directories in `/var/lib/sudo` and set their last modified date to 00:00 UTC on Thursday January first, 1970.

---

The reason that line exists was nicely explained in [the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154387/meaning-of-0-in-a-shell-script/154394?noredirect=1#comment252226_154394) below:

> @crisron The purpose of the line is to ensure that all sudo passwords from any previous instance of sudo are expired. The first time a user runs sudo, for each session it'll create a file in that directory. Sudo then checks the time stamp on the file the next time you run it to decide whether or not to ask you for the password again. This line ensures that when the sudo daemon is restarted all passwords must be retyped the next time a user sudos something. –  krowe

Comment: What is the purpose of setting those files' and directories' last modified date to epoch?

Comment: @crisron no idea. Presumably to make sure they are older than any other files which is (again, presumably) used by something else. Perhaps there is a script that identifies the newest files and this ensures that none of the default ones are affected.

Comment: @crisron The purpose of the line is to ensure that all sudo passwords from any previous instance of sudo are expired. The first time a user runs sudo each session it'll create a file in that directory. Sudo then checks the time stamp on the file the next time you run it to decide weather or not to ask you for the password again. This line ensures that when the sudo deamon is restarted all passwords must be retyped next time a user sudos something.

Answer (score 5):

`@0` is the epoch date. And more generally @x is x seconds after the epoch. For instance:

```
$ touch -d @0 foo
$ TZ=UTC0 ls -l foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 vinc17 vinc17 0 1970-01-01 00:00:00 foo
```

Note: The `-d` option of the `touch` utility is [specified by POSIX but only with strings in ISO8601 forms](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html). Other forms of strings are specific to each implementation, and in particular, the @x form is a GNU extension.

Answer (score 4):

That line does the following:

**/var/lib/sudo** defines the working directory.

**-exec touch -d @0 '{}' \;** is the action to perform. Let's split it into parts:

**-exec** precedes the actual action.

**touch -d** changes file timestamps parsing the argument string and using it instead of current time.

**@0** is a timestamp that is equivalent to:

```
root@debian:/var/log# date -d @0
Wed Dec 31 21:00:00 ART 1969
```

So bottom line is:

When the find command finds a hit, update the timestamp to Wed Dec 31 21:00:00 ART 1969.